# Align left and right elements contained in a parent div

Tags: html, css

I want the text `Immunization coverage` with a purple background to be on the left, while the text `HIT` and the switch are aligned to the right.

Also I would like the switch to be on the left of `HIT`.

How can I do?

```css
#legendRectContainer {
 border: 1px solid black;
}

 /* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 26px;
 height: 15px;
 background-color: lime;
 margin-top: 3.5px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
 display: none;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #ccc;
 -webkit-transition: .4s;
 transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 left: 2px;
 bottom: 2px;
 background-color: white;
 -webkit-transition: .4s;
 transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
 background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(11px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(11px);
 transform: translateX(11px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
 border-radius: 15px;
}

.slider.round:before {
 border-radius: 50%;
} 

#legendRectRow {
 background-color: yellow;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
#titleLegendRectRow {
 float: left;
}
#switchTitleLegendRectRow {
 background-color: orange;
 float: right;
}
#switchLegendRectRow {
 text-align: right;
 float: right;
}
#switchAndHit {
 border: 1px solid green;
}

#svgLegendRectRect text {
 font-size: 7pt;
 font-weight: 100;
}

.legendLinAxis path, .legendLinAxis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: none;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.legendLinG .tick line {
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}

.chartTitle {
 font-weight: 500;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: DeepPink;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='columnFooter' id='legendRectContainer'>
  <div id='legendRectRow'>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='titleLegendRectRow'>
      <p class='chartTitle'>Immunization coverage</p>
    </div>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='switchTitleLegendRectRow'>HIT</div>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='switchLegendRectRow'>
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id='legendRectSwitchButton' autocomplete='off'>
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='legend-rect'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin-left: auto;` instead of `float:right`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you should not use `float`s along with `flexbox`:

```css
#legendRectRow {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
#legendRectContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: lime;
  margin-top: 3.5px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 11px;
  width: 11px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(11px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(11px);
  transform: translateX(11px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#legendRectRow {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#titleLegendRectRow {
  float: left;
}

#switchTitleLegendRectRow {
  background-color: orange;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}

#switchLegendRectRow {
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

#switchAndHit {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#svgLegendRectRect text {
  font-size: 7pt;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.legendLinAxis path,
.legendLinAxis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.legendLinG .tick line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.chartTitle {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: DeepPink;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='columnFooter' id='legendRectContainer'>
  <div id='legendRectRow'>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='titleLegendRectRow'>
      <p class='chartTitle'>Immunization coverage</p>
    </div>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='switchTitleLegendRectRow'>HIT</div>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='switchLegendRectRow'>
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id='legendRectSwitchButton' autocomplete='off'>
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='legend-rect'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just remove `display:flex` and just add `overflow:auto` to `#legendRectRow` id

```css
#legendRectContainer {
 border: 1px solid black;
}

 /* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 26px;
 height: 15px;
 background-color: lime;
 margin-top: 3.5px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
 display: none;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: #ccc;
 -webkit-transition: .4s;
 transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 height: 11px;
 width: 11px;
 left: 2px;
 bottom: 2px;
 background-color: white;
 -webkit-transition: .4s;
 transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
 background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
 box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(11px);
 -ms-transform: translateX(11px);
 transform: translateX(11px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
 border-radius: 15px;
}

.slider.round:before {
 border-radius: 50%;
} 

#legendRectRow {
 background-color: yellow;
 overflow:auto;
 align-items: center;
}
#titleLegendRectRow {
 float: left;
}
#switchTitleLegendRectRow {
 background-color: orange;
 float: right;
}
#switchLegendRectRow {
 text-align: right;
 float: right;
}
#switchAndHit {
 border: 1px solid green;
}

#svgLegendRectRect text {
 font-size: 7pt;
 font-weight: 100;
}

.legendLinAxis path, .legendLinAxis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: none;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.legendLinG .tick line {
 stroke: black;
 stroke-width: 1px;
}

.chartTitle {
 font-weight: 500;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: DeepPink;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='columnFooter' id='legendRectContainer'>
  <div id='legendRectRow'>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='titleLegendRectRow'>
      <p class='chartTitle'>Immunization coverage</p>
    </div>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='switchTitleLegendRectRow'>HIT</div>
    <div class='colTitleRowLegendRect' id='switchLegendRectRow'>
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id='legendRectSwitchButton' autocomplete='off'>
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id='legend-rect'></div>
</div>
```

tell me if any other question